# FFmpeg match hex color exactly

Tags: video, ffmpeg, colors

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to generate a video with a color background using the following command.

```
ffmpeg.exe -t 5 -f lavfi -i color=c=0x1E3932:s=1094x863 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output_test.mp4
```

But the wrong green is generated; I'm getting `#1B3531` when I take a screenshot of the video and sample the color. I need it to match the background of the color on a website which is why I need that specific codec and pixel format. I can't use webm or a different codec with the platforms/browsers I must support.

Is there anyway to get a `color` source to output the correct hex value in the color space that I want? Is there some way to use the `colorspace` or `colormatrix` filter to achieve this effect (as from my understanding, this color shift comes from the conversion from RGB to YUV)?

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, please check our sister site at https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What OS are you running? Is your screenshot tool affected by display color profiles?

Comment: Windows 10 Home x64, whatever the latest slow ring build is. Screenshot program was Windows native Print Screen (not the snipping tool) pasted directly into Paint.NET to sample the color

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to matrix using -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709 and tag output using -colorspace 1. I also recommend tagging -color_range tv (that is what scale defaults to),  tagging -color_trc iec61966_2_1 and tagging -color_primaries to bt709.